# Printing out arrays based on user input in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a program in which the user inputs text and the console prints that text in a 7 by 5 grid of asterisks.

e.g;

```
Enter a word:
a

**** 
    *
*****
*   *
*****
```

However I am having trouble identifying the characters and then letting the program know.

My attempt so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char a[7][6] = { 
"     ",
"     ",
"**** ",
"    *",
"*****",
"*   *",
"*****"
};

...other letters... 

char word[20];
int i;
int j;
char letter[2];

int main() {//main

fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);

for (j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++) {
strcpy(letter, word[j]);
    for (i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", letter[i]);
    }
}

printf("Total number of characters processed: %d\n", strlen(word) - 1);

return (0);
}//*main
```

Letters are made in an individual array and printed line by line via loop in order for them to be printed one after the other horizontally.

My best idea was that variable `letter` which would change value to the current character being read from `word` but I know it is not correct.

Comment: Do you want to use only C or you can use also C++ features ? Btw I think it's a good way to map the entire letters in a grid of asterisks and then parse the input to a function that converts string/chars with the asterisk

Comment: One converted in a grid ( multidimensional array) you can print it horizontal

Comment: Just C. Would you mind expanding on what you mean? I was thinking of having all the letters in a 3d array but then I was not sure how to eventually call them out line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working example that prints a whole word in asterisk form (comments through the code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define maxchar 10      // number of characters in asterisk form
#define maxrows 6               // vertical length 
#define maxcols 5               // horizontal length
#define imax    5               // number of chars to be displayed in asterisk form

int main()
{
  // testing word with spaces
  char number[imax] = "92 02";

  // array of numbers
  char letter[maxrows][maxchar][maxcols] = 
    { //  j=0 ,    j=1 ,    j=2 ,    j=3 ,    j=4 ,    j=5 ,    j=6 ,    j=7 ,    j=8 ,    j=9
      { " ** ",  "*** ",  "*** ",  "*** ",  "*  *",  "****",  "*   ",  "****",  " ** ",  " ***" },  // row=0
      { "*  *",  "  * ",  "   *",  "   *",  "*  *",  "*   ",  "*   ",  "   *",  "*  *",  "*  *" },  // row=1
      { "*  *",  "  * ",  "   *",  " ** ",  "****",  "*** ",  "*** ",  "   *",  " ** ",  "*  *" },  // row=2
      { "*  *",  "  * ",  "*** ",  "   *",  "   *",  "   *",  "*  *",  "   *",  "*  *",  " ***" },  // row=3
      { "*  *",  "  * ",  "*   ",  "   *",  "   *",  "   *",  "*  *",  "   *",  "*  *",  "   *" },  // row=4
      { " ** ",  "****",  "****",  "*** ",  "   *",  "*** ",  "*** ",  "   *",  " ** ",  "   *" }   // row=5
    };


  // "iterators"
  int row, col, i;

  for(row=0; row < maxrows; ++row) // print from up to down
    {
      for(i=0; i < imax; ++i)      // for each character in array "number"
        {
          int j = number[i] - '0'; // get position in "letter". For characters, change to  j = number[i] - 'a';

          if(j<0) 
            printf("    ");        // if number[i] is not a valid character, print a space   
          else
            for(col = 0; col < maxcols; ++col)    
              printf("%c", letter[row][j][col]);   // print each * at given row

          printf("  ");            // print a small space between characters
        }
      printf("\n");                // proceed to next row
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Although I used numbers instead of characters, minimal changes would fit your needs. For this code, `number[] = "92 02"` will be printed as:

```
  ***  ***          **   ***   
 *  *     *        *  *     *  
 *  *     *        *  *     *  
  ***  ***         *  *  ***   
    *  *           *  *  *     
    *  ****         **   ****
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put all of the letters into a single array:

```
char letters[26][7][6] = {{ 
    "     ",
    "     ",
    "**** ",
    "    *",
    "*****",
    "*   *",
    "*****"
    },
    {
    "*    ",
    "*    ",
    "*    ",
    "*    ",
    "*****",
    "*   *",
    "*****"
    },
    ...
};
```

Then you can get the right one like this:

```
int letterIdx;
for (j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++) {
    // make sure this character is a letter, if not go to the next one
    if (!isalpha(word[i]) continue;
    // subtract the ASCII value of 'a' from the ASCII value of
    // the lower case version of the current letter to get a number between 0 and 25
    letterIdx = tolower(word[i]) - 'a';  
    for (i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", letters[letterIdx][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit further? Specifically the 3rd and 4th line as well as how would the program use the input to look for the right combination of letters in the array.